Question about MASH (ΣΔ) time domain ADPLL model from Syllaios paper
I have been trying to implement the ADPLL in time domain from Syllaios paper in Octave. The ADPLL is locking from my simulations (and fractional), but I have a question which I don't know how to implement it:
my question is for the MASH
for i=2:len %each FREF cycle
  % Accumulate FCW
  R_R(i)   = R_R(i-1) + FCW; 

  %crystal reference
  tr(i)    = (i-1) * t_ref + jitter_reference;

  %OTW Integer
  OTW_i(i) = floor(OTW(i-1));
  OTW_f(i) = OTW(i-1) - OTW_i(i);

How do I apply the OTW_f to the Mash?
The paper has the pseudo code, and I am stuck trying to apply OTW_f to the Sigma Delta modulator.
paper: I. L. Syllaios, R. B. Staszewski and P. T. Balsara, "Time-Domain Modeling of an RF All-Digital PLL," in IEEE Transactions on Circuits and Systems II: Express Briefs, vol. 55, no. 6, pp. 601-605, June 2008, doi: 10.1109/TCSII.2007.916845
the pseudo code:


Okay, there looks like there's some content in this question.  I need time to grok it.

thanks, I have not access to grok, but is so powerful to generate code  for adpll?

For Sigma Delta implementations (MASH or otherwise) the dither is typically applied prior to the quantizer (quantizers for MASH) to randomize what would otherwise be pattern noise resulting in narrow band tones (spurs) in the output result. The dither increases the spurious free dynamic range (if limited by spurs and not the broadband noise itself) at the expense of increasing the noise floor.
What I typically do is create an independent pseudo-random noise (with an LFSR or the remainder of the frequency control word as was done in this application), sum it to the accumulated output just prior to the quantizer with a scaling level that I can adjust. I then determine the optimum scaling empirically by adjusting the scale used while observing the frequency spectrum of the output. We want just enough scale to reduce the spurs while minimizing the total added noise.
Advanced techniques can be employed at the expense of further complexity to introduce band limited noise with energy outside of the sigma delta band by high pass or bandpass filtering the pseudo random noise prior to summing into the Sigma Delta.
